# Using same ViewController files for 2 Storyboards (to get identical views)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I am building my first single view app. I have my UI elements in my main storyboard. I arranged all of my elements based on the 3.5inch screen and now it looks good. I want the app looks good on 4-inch display as well. And now I created a 4-inch storyboard (blank) and I want to have similar views with exactly the same outlets shown, just change the layouts and positions to fit the 4 inch screen.

I thought I could create a separate storyboard view for different layout but use the same view controller files (.h and .m) so everything (the buttons and labels, etc.) works in the same way but I don't know to do it. Is this a correct idea and if yes how to accomplish it?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can... But there is no need for that! You should be interested in `autolayout`.
Here is a two-part [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/) on how to do that.

Of course you can use the same classes for other Storyboard. This is exactly what you do when you're developing Universal application. But in this case you'll have to put some assumptions in your code for determining whether you're using 4 inch or 3.5 inch screen. **Preprocessor instructions will be helpful** for you.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve your main objective:

1. having only one storyboard item with autolayouts that will auto
   adjust the screen for 3.5/4 inch
2. if you don't like autolayout and the view it's not to complicated, the "springs and struts" can achieve as well auto resize.
3. you can have both 3.5 and 4 inch view controllers in the same storyboard, access one or the other with "self.storyboard instantiateviewcontrollerwithidentifier"
4. you can have as many storyboards as you like and do UIStoryboard *storybord = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName..

PS: I'm a fan of option 2. It's usually worth to have 2 storyboards when the app is universal, so you'll have one fore iPhone and one for iPad.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I have tried autolayout and it doesn't work well. I have created a second storyboard already and can initiate   if the screen is 4-inch. But it is empty right now and I don't know how to put(copy) what I have in the first storyboard into the new one so that I can move certain elements. Can you explain in more details of option 2?

Comment: select the root view of your vc, do copy, go to the other storyboard, select the rootview and do paste